# MySQL-Masking credit card numbers but keeping the hyphens

Tags: masking

I need to return a column of credit card numbers from DB table 'orders' column is 'card_number'. They are in this format on the 'orders' table:

> 1234-5678-9012-3456

I need the SELECT statement to return with this:

> xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-3456

I've found examples without hyphens and adding hyphens where there are none showing this. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-', RIGHT(card_number,4)) FROM orders
```

`RIGHT(card_number,4)` gets the last 4 characters of `card_number`. It is concatenated to the end of the string `'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-'`

See [RIGHT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_right) and [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: Thank you so much. That was so helpful.